# Maximum number of comparisons required to define a partial ordering

Tags: order-theory

Given any possible partial ordering of size $n$, what is the maximum number of comparisons needed to define the partial ordering?  As an example, the partial orderings for size 4 are:

1 : No comparisons 
2 : $A < B$
3 : $A < B, A < C$ 
4 : $A < C, B < C$ 
5 : $A < B, C < D$ 
6 : $A < B, B < C$ 
7 : $A < C, B < C, B < D$ 
8 : $A < B, A < C, A < D$
9 : $A < D, B < D, C < D$
10: $A < C, A < D, B < C, B < D$
11: $A < B, B < C, A < D$
12: $A < D, B < C, C < D$
13: $A < B, B < C, B < D$
14: $A < C, B < C, C < D$
15: $A < B, A < C, B < D, C < D$
16: $A < B, B < C, C < D$

Here, partial orders 10 and 15 each require 4 comparisons in order to be defined.  So for 4 elements, at most 4 comparisons are needed to define any partial ordering.  I'm wondering if it is known the maximum number of comparisons needed to define any partial ordering of a $n$-element set.

I used this image of the Hasse diagrams of order 4 to construct the list.  This may be less confusing to look at than the list I provided.  Comparisons here are represented by the number of edges in the graph.   https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDLF7.jpg

Comment: It isn't very clear what you are asking for. To *define* a partial ordering you need to give negative information as well as positive information, e.g., your example 3 could be the same ordering as your example 6. Are you asking for the minimum number of pairs in a relation whose transitive closure is the desired partial ordering?

Comment: For the first part of your comment, any comparison I did not list is negative information.  So for 3, I never state that $B < C$ either explicitly or implicitly, so it is implied that $B$ and $C$ are incomparable.  It sounds like "the minimum number of pairs in a relation whose transitive closure is the desired partial ordering" is along the lines of what I'm asking.

Comment: Actually, I'm thinking more of a sequence where given n elements, it tells you the maximum number of the minimum number of pairs in a relation whose transitive closure is the desired partial ordering for all partial orderings of n elements.  So for 0 elements, it would be 0, 1 element would be 0, 2 elements would be 1, 3 elements would be 2, 4 elements would be 4, etc.

Comment: I suspected the complete bipartite graph might be the answer after posting this question.  That is indeed the answer, thanks.

Comment: In that case I'll post that comment as an answer.

Comment: The number of comparisons is not necessarily the same as the number of edges.  If I find $A \lt B$ and $B \lt C$  I know $A \lt C$ without doing the comparison.  In total orders of $n$ items there are $\frac 12n(n-1)$ edges but you only need $n \log n$ comparisons.  http://oeis.org/A000112 has the number of partial orders on $n$ elements.

Comment: @RossMillikan The [Hasse diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram) of a total order of $n$ items has just $n-1$ edges.

Comment: @bof:  OK, but you have to be lucky in which comparisons you do to pick out a partial order from the list.  As I read the question, it is equivalent to the $n \log n$ bound for sorting-what is the maximum number of comparisons that are needed to know which partial order you have.  In the total order case you can (if you are lucky) find the order in $n-1$ comparisons but we are interested in the case where you are not lucky.  I don't know the answer, but I suspect the number of edges in the Hasse diagram is not it.

Comment: @RossMillikan I see nothing in the question to suggest that he's probing to discover an unknown p;artial order; rather, he has a specific partial order in mind and wants to **define** it as concisely as possible. In a comment he speaks more explicitly about "the minimum number of pairs in a relation whose transitive closure is the desired partial ordering."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In other words, you are asking for the maximum number of edges in the [Hasse diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram) of a partially ordered set with $n$ elements. The answer is $\left\lfloor\frac{n^2}4\right\rfloor$,which by [Mantel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n%27s_theorem) is the maximum number of edges in a triangle-free graph on $n$ vertices. That's because the Hasse diagram of a partially ordered set is a triangle-free graph, and because the maximum in Mantel's theorem is attained by the complete bipartite graph $K_{\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor,\left\lceil\frac n2\right\rceil}$, which can be realized as the Hasse diagram of a partially ordered set of height two.

Comment: For the records: http://oeis.org/A002620